# parse properties of multiple components

Tags: json, angular

I've got a bunch of components of different types, that are created on the fly. When it's time, I would like to parse some state properties of each component and send them to server in JSON format.

for example, each `box` component has state properties: `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`. JSON for all the boxes would look like this:

```
{
projectName:"SOMENAME", 
projectDate:"SOMEDATE", 
boxes:[
  {x:1,y:12,width:123, height:321},
  {x:19,y:12,width:773, height:21},
  {x:876,y:122,width:3, height:31}
 ]
}
```

The order matters. After the box component is created, it is also manipulated, and changes need to be updated in the JSON model.

The way I would do this is to give each component a unique identifier and create a separate data class called `Data`. This class would have a field `projectName`, `projectDate` and array `boxes` that also stores unique identifier. I would than call `JSON.stringify()` on the whole object of type `Data` and send that to server.

Is this the way to go? Does angular have some preferred of solving this issue I described? What method do you recommend?

HTML

```
<app-box-component *ngFor="let box of boxes"> </app-box-component>
```

BoxComponent.ts

```
export class BoxComponent implements onInit{

//state properties that need to be send to server. Collected from every box component. 
x:number;
y:number;
width:number;
height:number;

}
```

Comment: Please,put  some more codes for clear understanding of the problem.

Comment: sure, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of dealing with state in Angular app is [ngrx](https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b) store.
In your case when user interacts with a box it can send a message like `BoxUpdated` and inside ngrx effects you would propagate this change to the server. Your ngrx store could contain all initial box data.